# Why isn't this fstream command working?

Tags: c++, fstream

Here's the code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    ifstream myfile;
    myfile.open("numbers.txt");

    if (myfile.is_open()){
        cout <<" okay to proceed" << endl;
    } else {
        cout<< "error finding file" <<endl;
    }
}
```

The file is as named, exactly and in the same folder as the program.

What am I doing wrong?   The is_open() check is failing >_<

Edit: Solved.   Found the working directory under product - scheme - options

Comment: The file must be in the working directory of the program execution, not the program source file.

Comment: Did you open it to read?

Comment: Do you have permissions to read this file?

Comment: If you're using Visual Studio, it executes in the project source directory (by the `.vcproj`) by default, so it will look for the file there.

Comment: It's a simple text file with 10 numbers.
I have permission to read it.
@hmjd I'm not quite sure what you mean.  (novice moment) how do i change the working directory or find out where it is in xcode?

Comment: It works as intended. The file must be in the *working directory* of the executable. This is not necessarily the directory that the executable is in.

Comment: @ChristopherBaldwin you can check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13225500/how-to-change-the-working-directory-to-the-location-of-the-program).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plenty of reasons:
1. No r permission (no access to read file)
2. "numbers.txt" is in some other directory, not one application was started
...
Use full path in myfile.open("FULLPATH/numbers.txt"); just to be sure you are open correct file.
Than check access rights (OS dependent)

Comment: Thanks!  The full path is probably a better practice than forcing a working directory change.

Comment: Note it just to test.

Comment: In common case, relative path is preferrable for UNIX-like. For WIN, full path always better