# Unable to Open .txt File

Tags: c++, fstream

```
std::ifstream infile;   
infile.open("example.txt");

if (!infile.is_open()) {        
   std::cout << "can't open" << std::endl;  
}
```

I read this: [unable to open file stream c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30629809/unable-to-open-file-stream-c) and have tried using the full path `infile.open("~/projects/example.txt");`

The text file is in the same folder where the `.cpp` / `.hpp` files reside.

What else could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try "realpath ~/projects/example.txt", which will show you the real path of your file, and then use this real path in your cpp

Answer (score 1):

I once had the same problem on Windows. The problem was that the actual file name was "example.txt.txt", but Window Explorer was configured (by default) to hide file extensions.

A simple solution is to use c++17 filesystem library. For example,   `current_path` will return what its name promises. Or write a simple function that will list the current path contents (see the example on cppreference, https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/fs/directory_iterator ) . Or create a file of some similar name, e.g. `__example__.txt` and see where it was created and under which name it is reported by your filesystem manager.

If this is Linux, try running your program under `strace` (`strace myprog myoptions`).