# How to change directory using a c program and display its directory

Tags: c, directory

I have tried using chdir and cd but and ran dir 
but both displayed the directory of the folder/project folder i am in.
Following is the source Code

```
system("chdir (C:/)");
system("dir");
```

and this

```
system("chdir C:/");
system("dir");
```

and this

```
system("cd C:/");
system("dir");
```

Comment: Isn't it obvius? -> `chdir (C:/)`? `system("dir")`???

Comment: I was just going to say that iharob :)

Comment: I think you can't change your shell's working directory, so you need a different approach, I have no solid base to say that, but I'am almost sure.

Comment: Try `system("chdir (C:/) && dir");`

Comment: If it's only to get the directory listing on DOS, no `cd` is necessary, just do `system("dir path-to-directory")`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Posix `chdir` function to change directory and then the Posix `opendir`, `readdir` and `closedir` methods to enumerate the contents of the directory.

Both of these questions have been covered before on SO. Please refer to:

[Change current working directory C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3485166/change-current-working-directory-c)

[How do you get a directory listing in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12489/how-do-you-get-a-directory-listing-in-c)

Answer (score 3):

by calling system() you are creating a sub process that will change directories but not your current process working directory.

try calling the function chdir as this post suggests: [Change the current working directory in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3485166/change-current-working-directory-c)

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, by calling [`system()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/system) function call, it will execute the `command` by calling `/bin/sh -c` and will return the exit status. The next call to `system()` will invoke another `/bin/sh -c`.

So, basically, for each call, a new *child* shell is used. Hence, you cannot expect the result of the first call to be preserved [*persistent*] in the second call. Your current process directory will *not* be affected. Next call to `system()` will consider the *old* current process directory itself.

You can try providing both the commands to be executed in a single call to `system()`, by joining them with `&&` or `;`

Answer (score 1):

I think you shouldn't use `system()` as it makes you program non-portable. (dir doesn't exist on Linux, for exemple)

You may use [opendir](http://manpagesfr.free.fr/man/man3/opendir.3.html) and [readdir](http://manpagesfr.free.fr/man/man3/readdir.3.html) in order to open a directory and list the files it contains.

Here is a simple example :

```
DIR *dp;
struct dirent *dptr;
if(NULL == (dp = opendir("C:")) )
{
    perror("Opendir");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
else
{
    while(NULL != (dptr = readdir(dp)) )
    {
        printf("%s ",dptr->d_name);
    }
    closedir(dp);
}
```

Comment: How would that change the program's current work directory?

Comment: It doesn't, that's just a different approch because he doesn't need to change the directory. This is another way to do the same thing : display the content of a directory.