# Set Default directory path in fstream in c++

Tags: c++, fstream

Can I set a default directory path to fstream in c++?
If I say,

```
fstream fPointer("file1.txt",ios::in);
```

It should locate the file from, **/home/[user]/[path]/file1.txt**

It should automatically locate the directory ( /home/[user]/[path]/ )
Whenever I use fstream or ofstream.

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3485166/change-current-working-directory-c

Comment: This is what the current working directory is for.

Comment: Don't hardcode paths like this. What if the user's home dir isn't `/home/[user]`? What if they don't have one? What if they don't wish to use it?

Answer (score 1):

fstream will open the file in the 'current' working directory (i.e. the directory the program was executed from).  If you want this to change, use cd (windows) or cwd (Linux?) to set the current working directory before executing the program.

Alternatively, just specify the full path to the file in your constructor.

Comment: For Linux it is `chdir()`

Comment: @Slava chdir() is a C function for changing the current direction /after/ running the program.  I was talking about the shell commands for changing directory before running the program.

Comment: shell command depends on shell and for sh/ksh/bash/csh it is `cd` not `cwd`. But this is programming question so it would be logical to tell OP how to change current dir in program.

Answer (score 1):

```
std::string myDefaultDirectory = "/home/[user]/[path]/";

...

fstream fPointer(
    myDefaultDirectory + "file1.txt",
    ios::in);
```

Comment: In C++98 you need `(myDefaultDirectory + "file1.txt").c_str()`