# How to have a C++ program run a cmd command

Tags: c++, cmd, adb

I am having troubles writing a C++ program that can run a command in cmd. I would like to have my C++ program run the following command `adb install NativeAndroidTest.apk` When I run this command in cmd, it works if I am in the same directory as `NativeAndroidTest.apk`, but not when I am in a different directory. That's ok, but no matter what I do, I can't get my C++ program to run the command.

The sample code:

```
#include <Windows>

int main() {

    system("cd C:\\Users\\brenden\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2017\\Projects\\NativeAndroidTest\\NativeAndroidTest\\NativeAndroidTest.Packaging\\ARM\Release");
    system("adb install NativeAndroidTest.apk");


    return 0;
}
```

I fixed the problem by changing the code to

```
_wchdir((wchar_t*)"C:\\Users\\brenden\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2017\\Projects\\NativeAndroidTest\\NativeAndroidTest\\NativeAndroidTest.Packaging\\ARM\\Release");
system("adb install NativeAndroidTest.apk");
```

Thanks for the help. If someone adds a proper answer I'll mark it as correct so you get points.

I'd like to mention, just in case someone else reads this, trying to cast a string to a wchar pointer is a bad Idea, and my program only worked because of a fluke (I had the apk stored in the program's working directory).

you should convert the string to a wchar pointer with a function like this

```
wstring Commands::convertStringToWstring(const std::string &input) {
   wchar_t* buffer = new wchar_t[input.size() * 2 + 2];
   swprintf(buffer, L"%S", input.c_str());
   std::wstring returnWstring = buffer;
   delete[] buffer;
   return returnWstring;
}
```

Comment: Are you calling that via the `system()` function?

Comment: I did try using the system function system("adb install NativeAndroidTest.apk"); I couldn't seem to get it to work, even when I placed NativeAndroidTest.apk in C:

Comment: What have you that failed?

Comment: have you tried switching the working directory using cd command?

Comment: use `chdir`. or simply use full paths.

Comment: Your program needs to run in the same working directory where `NativeAndroidTest.apk` exists, or you have to pass the full path of that file.

Comment: How are you compiling the C++?  How are you executing it?  If you are using Visual Studio, you probably want to set the current directory in which to execute the program.

Comment: @MuhammadNizami `system("cd ...")` doesn't work.

Comment: When I run the command normally in cmd, and supply the full path I get Invalid APK file: error, but if I run the command in the same directory as the apk file it works perfectly

Comment: @holycatcrusher As mentioned `system("cd ...")` doesn't work. Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3485166/change-the-current-working-directory-in-c) how to change your programs current working directory.

Comment: The system() function call starts a shell (cmd if you're on Windows) and runs the command that you specify within it. Each call to system() will start a separate shell. The "cd" command only applies to the shell that it's run in, not to the program that you call it from. That means that the "cd" command in the first call to system() will have no effect on the second call to system(). As others have commented, you should either call chdir() from your program before calling system("adb install ..."), or specify the full path in the "adb install".

Comment: @holycatcrusher "_supply the full path I get Invalid APK file_": Did you remember to enclose the path in double-quotes? Something like: `adb install "C:\\Users\\brenden\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2017\\Projects\\NativeAndroidTest\\NativeAndroidTest\\NativeAndroidTest.Packaging\\ARM\Release\NativeAndroidTest.apk"`

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ you were right, I had to use _wchdir. I fixed the problem.

Comment: Why are you using _wchdir instead of _chdir? In any case, you are creating a wide string literal incorrectly.

Comment: @Klitos Kyriacou because it was the one that auto complete suggested. After checking, I don't think _chdir is in the Windows.h header.

Comment: You can't convert from char* to wchar_t* via C-style cast. Using wide chars is really simple, however, just add an L in front of the quote, like L"C:\\...".

Comment: If you are using windows, you may also try CreateProcess.