# Creating a command prompt process that opens at a chosen directory

Tags: c++, winapi, createprocess

Need help here, I'm trying to create a process in c++ with the windows api, whats happening is the process is being created which is cmd.exe however I want cmd.exe to open cd'd at a certain directory i.e. root c:\, however the process is opened at the dir of the executable.
I tried passing in "cd \" as the second argument of the CreateProcess function to no avail

Here's a snippet of the code:

```
TCHAR program[] = TEXT("C:/Windows/System32/cmd.exe");
TCHAR command[] = TEXT("cd /");
STARTUPINFO info;
PROCESS_INFORMATION processInfo;
ZeroMemory(&info,sizeof(STARTUPINFO));
ZeroMemory(&processInfo,sizeof(PROCESS_INFORMATION));

BOOL processResult =
CreateProcess(program,
            command, NULL, NULL,
            TRUE, CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE,
            NULL, NULL,
            &info,
            &processInfo);

if(!processResult){
 std::cerr << "CreateProcess() failed to start program \""
 << program << "\"\n";
 exit(1);
}

std::cout << "Started program \""
<< program << "\" successfully\n";
```

Help would be extremely appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: [edit] Cd to the directory, then run the process. Check out.[/edit] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3485166/change-the-current-working-directory-in-c

Comment: You could use `ShellExecute` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the `cd /` (or any other command) to have any effect, you need to use either the `/k` or `/c` flags for the command prompt. You can look these switches up in the documentation for `cmd.exe`, but basically, `/c` runs the command and then terminates, while `/k` runs the command and keeps the console session open. You almost certainly want `/k` here.

But really, you should be specifying the directory as the *working directory* for the process, not executing a change-directory command.

You can do this easily by calling the [`ShellExecute` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153.aspx), as Raw N suggested. The working directory is one of its parameters. `ShellExecute` (or `ShellExecuteEx`) is easier to use than `CreateProcess`, and should be preferred unless you need some special low-level behavior that you can only get with `CreateProcess`.

This works with `CreateProcess` too: pass the path as the `lpCurrentDirectory` parameter.

Whatever you do, **don't hard-code paths**! Use the `%comspec%` environment variable on Windows NT. It would also work to just execute `cmd`, letting the default search paths do their job.

Comment: `ShellExecuteEx()` should always be used instead of `ShellExecute()` because the latter has poor error reporting (only a limited set of non-standard return values). It should also be noted that `CreateProcess()` has less overhead than `ShellExecute()`.

Comment: Perfectly detailed answer and answers everything that I wanted and more, thank you