# Writing to .csv file in C++

Tags: c++, xcode, csv

I'm trying to output data to a `.csv` file, but when I run the program it does not change the output file. It is as if I have not run the program at all. It builds successfully.

I created this project in XCode. The `".xcodeproject"` and `"example.csv"` files are located in the working directory (**Desktop** -> **ofstream**). `"main.cpp"` is located in **Desktop** -> **ofstream** -> **ofstream** and is the only file in that folder. I am using "Release" for builds.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    std::ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open ("example.csv");
    myfile << "This is the first cell in the first column.\n";
    myfile << "a,b,c,\n";
    myfile << "c,s,v,\n";
    myfile << "1,2,3.456\n";
    myfile << "semi;colon";
    myfile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

What am I missing to successfully write into this `.csv` file?

Comment: "What am I missing to successfully write into this .csv file?" I'm not sure. What exactly is the problem you're having? Could you be more specific?

Comment: Either `myfile.open ("example.csv");` is failing, which you are not checking for, or the Current Working Directory of the calling process is not what you are expecting, so `"example.csv"` gets written in some other folder.  You should never use relative file paths, always use absolute paths.  And add error checking.

Comment: Check that the call to `open()` worked ( add `if (myfile) {std::cerr << "Error\n";}`). If you are using an IDE it will "probably" be run in the same directory as the IDE (so look there for the 'example.csv'). You can try specifying a full path  "/tmp/example.csv" or you can change the current working directory. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3485166/change-the-current-working-directory-in-c

Comment: Using an absolute file path fixed the issue. Thank you all

Comment: Unable to reproduce problem.  The code compiled, created and wrote the expected 5 lines of content ... the location of the new file is the default directory where the code was compiled and run.