# How to implement the cd command in C++ on Window

Tags: c++, windows, cmd, console

Is it possible to change the directory in the calling CMD console from inside a C++ program on Windows?

I know there are many ways to change the working directory in the scope of a program, e.g. using `_chdir()`, but I would like directory change to be preserved when the program has exited.

I would like the behavior to be something like:

```
C:\Some\Path>MyProgram.exe

C:\Some\Other\Path>
```

(similar to calling `cd` inside the console)

One solution could be to wrap the program in a `.bat` file and then use output of the program as input to the `cd` command. However, I would like if that was not necessary.

Comment: is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3485166/change-the-current-working-directory-in-c) what you are looking for?

Comment: I don't think you can change the current directory of a parent process

Comment: @AryanParekh your suggestion will only change the working directory for the called program, not the parent process.

Comment: What happens if you use `CALL "MyProgram.exe"`?

Comment: @lit Nothing happens, the working directory for the program is changed, not the working directory inside command prompt

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have not checked but I'm pretty sure that you could execute [SetCurrentDirectoryW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setcurrentdirectory) in the parent process using [CreateRemoteThread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createremotethread).

The `SetCurrentDirectory` matches the `lpStartAddress` signature, so it should be possible to just allocate the z-terminated string with new directory path in the parent process memory space and pass this string as `lpParameter` to `CreateRemoteThread`. The trick is to get the address of `SetCurrentDirectory` **in the parent process**. You should enumerate parent process modules, and calculate the proper offset of the `SetCurrentDirectory` function using base address of `Kernel32.dll`.

To allocate the string you should use [VirtualAllocEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-virtualallocex) and write the value to allocated memory with [WriteProcessMemory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-writeprocessmemory). When the remote thread finished you should release memory with `VirtualFreeEx`.

Are you sure the batch is not easier solution?

Comment: I am not sure the cmd.exe window will be aware of the change to display it. You may have to inject a command to update as well.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that cmd.exe doesn't maintain CWD in some trickery way, so it should update prompt after the executable (which did the trick with CD) finishes.

Comment: I know the question is tagged as CMD, but seeing as the OP used the confused phrasing "CMD console" when CMD is a shell, not a console or terminal, it should be stressed that this technique doesn't necessarily apply to other shells that one can use in a console or terminal. In particular it doesn't apply to PowerShell, which has a higher-level concept of the working 'directory' in terms of drive providers (e.g. Registry) and -- last I checked -- ignores the process-level filesystem working directory.

Comment: In the question there was a note `wrap the program in a .bat file`. That confirms for me cmd.exe nature. But yes, the solution will not work for powershell or bash, because of completely different CD maintaining.