# How can I use terminal commands like pushd inside a C/C++ program Linux

Tags: c, linux, terminal, system

Disclaimer: I am not looking on how to use the `system()` function. I didn't really know how to phrase the title.

I am trying to use `pushd` (not only `pushd`, but this is the easiest example I could find) from inside a C program like this: `system("pushd ~");`, but I get the following message: `sh: 1: pushd: not found`

I think I may need something like a pipe, but I'm not sure, and I'm not very familiar as to how this works. Sorry for the vague question, I don't really know how to explain better. Thanks for the help!

Comment: What are you trying to do? `pushd` , isn't a program, it's just a shell instruction for manipulating the current directory (same applies for `cd`)

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3485166/change-the-current-working-directory-in-c

Comment: If it's "from inside a C program" then remove the C++ tag from your question. Otherwise have a look at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/current_path

Comment: @AlanBirtles My exact problem is the following: I have to run a program, and that program accesses some other files in the same directory, using a relative path. If I run the program like this: `system("/full_path/program");`, it will have problems when it tries to access the files that it needs, since it will use the relative path from where I ran the C program

Comment: @m88 Should I not use the C++ tag for questions that apply to both C or C++? I felt like maybe there are people looking through the C++ tags that would know the answer, since it applies to both languages. I will remove it though

Comment: [man 3 getcwd()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getcwd.3.html) ??

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I don't think it helps with what I want to do. From what I understand it gives me the path from where I run the C program, and I am not interested in that.

Comment: @H-005 Look at the C tag description, the last sentence.

Comment: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/chdir.2.html, even if your `system` command worked it would only apply inside the command, it wouldn't change the path of your process

Comment: @m88 Understood, thank you

Comment: @ypnos I think this works for what I want to do, thank you